# jOOQ - group by uses alias instead of columns

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-boot, jooq, listagg

I'm running jOOQ 3.13.6, on **Oracle 11g** springboot environment.

To use listagg function, I'm trying the solution provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69482329/17505774

Example code:

```
    @Autowired
    private DSLContext dsl;

    // setting tables
    Table table1 = DSL.table("table_1").as("t1");
    Table table2 = DSL.table("table_2").as("t2");

    // creating fields
    final List<Field<?>> fields = new ArrayList<Field<?>>();

    fields.add(DSL.field(DSL.name("t1", "t1_id")).as("id"));
    Field cf = DSL.field(DSL.name("t2", "t2_code")).as("code");
    fields.add(listAgg(cf, ";", null)); // no order

    // running query
    dsl.settings().withRenderQuotedNames(RenderQuotedNames.EXPLICIT_DEFAULT_UNQUOTED);

    dsl.select(fields)
            .from(table1)
            .join(table2).on("t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id")
            .where("t1.t1_id = ?", id)
            .groupBy(fields)
```

However, it executes the following query:

```
select t1.t1_id      id,
       listagg(t2.t2_code) within group (null) as code
  from table_1 t1
  join table_2 t2 on ( t1.t1_id = t2.t2_id )
 where t1.t1_id = 1
 group by id
```

The **group by** should use the original column names (t1.t1_id), not the alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, for this answer, and for brevity reasons, I'm assuming you had been using the [code generator](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/). The answer is the same without code generation usage.

#### Why the current behaviour?

[Note, this behaviour is also documented here in the manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/declaration-vs-reference/).

In jOOQ, an aliased column expression `T1.T1_ID.as("id")` can only generate 2 different versions of itself:

- `T1.T1_ID as ID`, i.e. the alias declaration (when inside of `SELECT`, at the top level)
- `ID`, i.e. the alias reference (when inside of any other clause / expression than the `SELECT` clause)

There isn't a third type of generated SQL that depends on the location of where you embed the alias expression, e.g. the unaliased column expression `T1.T1_ID` when you put the expression in `WHERE` or `GROUP BY`, etc. The rationale is simple. What would a user expect when they write:

```java
groupBy(T1.T1_ID.as("id"))
```

Why would they expect the `as()` call to be a no-op? That would be more surprising than the status quo.

#### Consistency with other rendering modes

There are other types of `QueryPart` in jOOQ, which have similar aliasing capabilities:

- `Field`
- `Table`
- `WindowSpecification`
- `Parameter`
- `CTE`

Let's look at the CTE example:

```java
Table<?> cte = name("cte").as(select(...))
```

That `cte` reference has 2 modes of rendering itself to SQL:

- The CTE declaration (if placed in the `WITH` clause)
- The CTE reference (if placed in `FROM`, etc.)

I don't think you'd expect that `cte` reference to ever ignore the aliasing, and just render the `SELECT` itself?

Likewise with table aliasing:

```java
T1 x = T1.as("x");
```

This can render itself as:

- The alias declaration (if placed in the `FROM` clause)
- The alias reference

Because the `FROM` clause is [*logically before*](https://blog.jooq.org/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/) any other clauses, you'd never expect your `x` reference to render only `T1`, instead of `x` or `T1 as x`, right?

So, for consistency reasons across the jOOQ API, the `Field` aliases must also behave like all the others.

#### What to do instead?

Don't re-use the alias expression outside of your `SELECT` clause. Write the jOOQ SQL exactly as you'd write the actual SQL:

```java
ctx.select(T1.T1_ID.as("id"), ...)
   .from(T1)
   .groupBy(T1.T1_ID)
   ...
```

Comment: I'm not using any code generator. The entities are already mapped using hibernate, but I need extract some data into a Json Format. That's the reason I extended using jooq

Comment: @MikeWallace: Understood, but for future readers of this question, I wanted to stress the many benefits of using the jOOQ code generator, one of which being that the jOOQ code is shorter. As you'll use jOOQ more often (possibly not only for JSON formatting), this is likely to apply to your use-case as well. You can even [generate code from JPA entities directly](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-jpa/)

Comment: What if the entites are not mapped by and the query is built dynamically?

Comment: @MikeWallace: If the schema isn't dynamic, you can still generate code in jOOQ and [build dynamic SQL using generated code](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/). If the schema is dynamic, then, of course, the code you've shown is the only way.